# error while installing npm package, how do i fix this?

Tags: javascript, npm

I need to install the react-hls-player npm package to start the m3u8 stream, but when I install it, it gives me this error.

[image]

Comment: basically myapp is not a react js folder where you are installing the package

Comment: I usually set the settings in the my-app folder, but how do you recommend setting it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Dunno why this was migrated. It’s a development question. // The error is clear, too: The React version you chose and the package you want are not (declared) compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the (very hard to see) screenshot it seems your app and `react-hls-player` require different versions of `react`. Hence the conflict of dependencies. You may have to force it or make it the same react version for both if `--legacy-peer-deps` doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--legacy-peer-deps` option. Try `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: The result is the same